# How to do API monitoring in Kong like viewing usage count/response code/consumption pattern etc?

Tags: api, prometheus, grafana, kong

I’ve just started exploring kong for monitoring my Restful APIs.
Before that I have been working on Gravitee.io
I want to know what is the best way to view my API usage pattern like:

1. Who called my API?
2. When it was called?
3. What was the error code/ response returned?
4. From which IP it was called?
   And other such details.these details are readily available in gravitiee.io, but in Kong (community edition)I m having a tough time finding Similar features.

I've heard about plugins such as Prometheus and grafana for API analysis.
I even added Prometheus plugin in my API. But what to do next I m not able to understand.
Please help me to view API analytics on some (free)dashboard .

Answer (score 2):

Prometheus and Grafana are generally used for matrices collection and visualization. Prometheus will collect metrics data and forward them to Grafana to show as graphs or charts.

What you are asking I presume is called logs analysis. In that case, you can use logging services like ELK(ElasticSearch, Logstash, and Kibana) with Kong the get your desired services. You can dump and analyze the log data as you want them to be. For example, which IP it came from, what time the API was called, what was the response etc.

**You can integrate these easily with Kong. Install the TCP/UDP Log Plugin, Export them to Logstash and ElasticSearch. Then view them with Kibana.**

If you use K8S, then you can use EFK which is ElasticSearch, Fluentd, and Kibana for analyzing the logs generated.

Answer (score 1):

I would completely agree with Shahed in the above answer mentioned about how to visualize the Logs generated by Kong.

Adding to the above answer I want to add few things that could be useful.

- **Http Log plugin** could be used to redirect the logs to the Elastic Search instance and later could be Visualized in Kibana.
- There is **no feature to see the Request and Response body** which has been a request from the developers sincle long. Check [here](https://discuss.konghq.com/t/logging-request-body-response-body-with-http-log/1205/6)

I am still not sure why the [PR for including Resquest and Response Body is still not Merged](https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/3028)